# How to know if a foreign key has cascade on delete clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Due to a misconception of the **PostgreSQL** database I work with everyday, on the 155 tables that the schema of the database contains, some tables with foreign key doesn't have the '**on delete cascade**' clause which cause serious trouble as you can expect.

I would like to correct this and with PGAdmin I'm able to see all FK of a table but not if the FK as the clause. Instead of, for each tables, dropping manually each FK and creating new ones with the 'on delete cascade', I would like to know how, for a specific table, the full definition of the foreign keys. Like this I will not drop foreign keys that already has the clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look in `pg_constraint`:

```
postgres=# create table car (id int primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table driver (id int, car int references car(id) on delete cascade);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# select connamespace, conname, c.relname as child_table, p.relname as parent_table, confdeltype 
from pg_constraint 
join pg_class c on c.oid=conrelid 
join pg_class p on p.oid=confrelid;
 connamespace |     conname     | child_table | parent_table | confdeltype 
--------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------
         2200 | driver_car_fkey | driver      | car          | c
(1 row)
```

This will show you all the foreign keys (along with their source and target tables) that do not have `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
select connamespace, conname, c.relname as child_table, p.relname as parent_table, confdeltype
from pg_constraint 
join pg_class c on c.oid=conrelid 
join pg_class p on p.oid=confrelid
where confdeltype <> 'c';
```

More information in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

This query will show all foreign constraints that are defined without cascading delete and the tables on which they are defined:

```
SELECT conname AS constraint_name,
       conrelid::regclass AS table
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE contype = 'f'
  AND confdeltype <> 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints can be queried from [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html). Foreign key constraints have an `'f'` in the column `contype`. The delete action can be taken from the column `confdeltype`. For cascading action it holds a `'c'`. So you want all constraints where `contype` is `'f'` and `confdeltype` isn't `'c'`.

You can join [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) for the involved tables and [`pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html) for their schemas. That way you can also limit the search to the tables of a specific schema.

In `conkey` the referencing and in `confkey` the referenced are stored as array of the ordinal numbers of the columns in the respective table. You can get the names from [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html).

The following query would give you all foreign key constraints on any table in the schema `public` which's delete action isn't cascade along with the tables' schema names and the columns involved in the constraint.

```
SELECT con.conname,
       con.confdeltype,
       nsp.nspname,
       rel.relname,
       (SELECT array_agg(att.attname ORDER BY un.ord)
               FROM unnest(con.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY un (attnum, ord)
                    INNER JOIN pg_attribute att
                               ON att.attnum = un.attnum
               WHERE att.attrelid = rel.oid) conkeyattnames,
       fnsp.nspname,
       frel.relname,
       (SELECT array_agg(att.attname ORDER BY un.ord)
               FROM unnest(con.confkey) WITH ORDINALITY un (attnum, ord)
                    INNER JOIN pg_attribute att
                               ON att.attnum = un.attnum
               WHERE att.attrelid = frel.oid) confkeyattnames
       FROM pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = rel.relnamespace
            INNER JOIN pg_class frel
                       ON frel.oid = con.confrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_namespace fnsp
                       ON fnsp.oid = frel.relnamespace
       WHERE con.contype = 'f'
             AND con.confdeltype <> 'c'
             AND nsp.nspname = 'public';
```